# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 5000), indices imply (2, 1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chunks

I am trying to do a recommendation system. Here is my code:

```
# Load the CSV data in chunks
chunk_size = 5000
data_chunks = pd.read_csv("books_with_blurbs.csv", chunksize=chunk_size)

# Initialize the TF-IDF vectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store recommendations
recommendations_dict = {'Title': [], 'Recommendations': []}


# Define the content-based recommender function
def content_based_recommender(title, cosine_sim, chunk_df):
    indices = pd.Series(chunk_df.index, index=chunk_df["Title"])
    book_index = indices[title]
    similarity_scores = pd.DataFrame(cosine_sim[book_index], columns=["score"])
    book_indices = similarity_scores.sort_values("score", ascending=False)[1:11].index
    return chunk_df['Title'].iloc[book_indices].tolist()
```

When I try to call these functions for chunks:

```
# Process each chunk of data
for chunk_number, data_chunk in enumerate(data_chunks, start=1):
    print(f"Processing Chunk {chunk_number}")

    # Calculate cosine similarity matrix for the current chunk
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(data_chunk['Blurb'].fillna(''))
    cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

    # Get recommendations for each book in the current chunk
    for title in data_chunk['Title']:
        recommendations = content_based_recommender(title, cosine_sim, data_chunk)
        recommendations_dict['Title'].append(title)
        recommendations_dict['Recommendations'].append(recommendations)
```

The first chunk processed but after that python gives "**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 5000), indices imply (2, 1)**" error. Is there anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: line that raised the error? It looks like you could work your question MUCH closer to an MRE, like https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @OCa see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)